# An empty result may be returned when using ReactiveNeo4jTemplate's findAll method with a Statement parameter

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have an issue with ReactiveNeo4jTemplate and the `findAll` method using a `Statement`. All the template methods work except this one, which returns an empty result even though the database has nodes that match the `Statement`. I have a test that updates all the elements that match certain criteria, but it fails because the `findAll` with `Statement` does not return any value, so it does not perform the update. However, the `findAll` without any search criteria finds all the elements.

This is the implementation of the method that updates any data in a Statement.

```kotlin
class Neo4jQueryableRepositoryAdapter<T : Any, ID : Any>(
    private val delegator: Neo4jRepository<T, ID>,
    clazz: KClass<T>
) : QueryableRepository<T, ID>, Repository<T, ID> by delegator {
    private val parser = Neo4jCriteriaParser(clazz)
 
// More code and functions here

override fun updateAll(
        criteria: Criteria,
        patch: Patch<T>,
        limit: Int?,
        offset: Long?,
        sort: Sort?
    ): Flow<T> {
        return parser.parse(criteria).let { delegator.updateAll(it, patch, limit, offset, sort) }
    }

// More code and functions here

}
```

The implementation of my `Neo4jRepository` interface is located in the `SimpleNeo4jRepository` class.

```kotlin
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class SimpleNeo4jRepository<T : Any, ID : Any>(
    private var template: ReactiveNeo4jTemplate,
    val clazz: KClass<T>,
    eventPublisher: EventPublisher? = null,
) : Neo4jRepository<T, ID> {

// More code and functions

override fun updateAll(
        criteria: Statement,
        patch: Patch<T>,
        limit: Int?,
        offset: Long?,
        sort: Sort?
    ): Flow<T> {
        return updateAll(criteria, patch.async(), limit, offset, sort)
    }

override fun updateAll(
        criteria: Statement,
        patch: SuspendPatch<T>,
        limit: Int?,
        offset: Long?,
        sort: Sort?
    ): Flow<T> {
        return findAll(criteria, limit, offset, sort)
            .map { update(it, patch) }
            .filterNotNull()
    }

override fun findAll(criteria: Statement?, limit: Int?, offset: Long?, sort: Sort?): Flow<T> {
            // Validate the limit and offset
            val l = limit ?: Int.MAX_VALUE
            val o = offset ?: 0

            // Perform custom search if criteria are specified
            val all = if (criteria != null) {
                println("QUERY ➡️ ${criteria.cypher}")
                template.findAll(criteria, clazz.java)
            } else {
                template.findAll(clazz.java)
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .asFlow()

            // Apply limit and offset and return results
            return all.drop(o.toInt()).take(l)
    }

// More code and Functions

}
```

The configuration class is as follows

```kotlin
import com.astrum.data.annotation.ConverterScope
import org.neo4j.driver.AuthTokens
import org.neo4j.driver.Driver
import org.neo4j.driver.GraphDatabase
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.GenericConverter
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment
import org.springframework.data.convert.ReadingConverter
import org.springframework.data.convert.WritingConverter
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.AbstractReactiveNeo4jConfig
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.convert.Neo4jConversions
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableReactiveNeo4jRepositories
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement

@Configuration
@EnableReactiveNeo4jRepositories("com.astrum")
@EnableTransactionManagement
class Neo4jConfiguration(
    private val applicationContext: ApplicationContext,
    private val env: Environment
) : AbstractReactiveNeo4jConfig() {

    @Bean
    override fun neo4jConversions(): Neo4jConversions {
        val converters = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(GenericConverter::class.java)
            .values
            .filter {
                it.javaClass.annotations.any { annotation ->
                    annotation is WritingConverter || annotation is ReadingConverter
                }
            }
            .filter {
                val scope = it.javaClass.annotations.filterIsInstance<ConverterScope>()
                scope.isEmpty() || scope.any { converterScope -> converterScope.type == ConverterScope.Type.NEO4J }
            }
        return Neo4jConversions(converters)
    }
    /**
     * The driver to be used for interacting with Neo4j.
     *
     * @return the Neo4j Java driver instance to work with.
     */
    @Bean
    override fun driver(): Driver {
        val uri = env.getProperty("spring.data.neo4j.uri") ?: "bolt://localhost:7687"
        val username = env.getProperty("spring.data.neo4j.username") ?: "neo4j"
        val password = env.getProperty("spring.data.neo4j.password") ?: "password"
        return GraphDatabase.driver(uri, AuthTokens.basic(username, password))
    }
}
```

This is the test that is failing when I use `findAll` with `Statement`, if I change it to just use `findAll` without `Statement` the test passes because of course it finds the node (but that's not the idea)

```kotlin
@Test
    fun updateAllByName() = parameterized { personRepository ->
        val person = DummyPerson.create()
            .let { personRepository.create(it) }
        val patch = DummyPerson.create()
        
                // just for check
        var all = personRepository.findAll(where(Person::name).`is`(person.name)).toList()
        println("all persons ✅: $all")

        val updatedPersons = personRepository.updateAll(
            where(Person::name).`is`(person.name),
            Patch.with {
                it.name = patch.name
                it.age = patch.age
            }
        ).toList()
 
        // just for check
        all = personRepository.findAll(where(Person::name).`is`(person.name)).toList()
        println("all persons ❌: $all")

        assertEquals(1, updatedPersons.size)
        val updatedPerson = updatedPersons[0]
        assertEquals(person.id, updatedPerson.id)
        assertEquals(patch.name, updatedPerson.name)
        assertEquals(patch.age, updatedPerson.age)
        assertNotNull(updatedPerson.updatedAt)
    }
```

This code is to test if the `findAll` function was working properly with the Criteria to Statement Converter.

```kotlin
        var all = personRepository.findAll(where(Person::name).`is`(person.name)).toList()
        println("all persons ✅: $all")
```

Excerpts from the prints

all persons ✅: [Person(name=arletha.dietric, age=67)]

QUERY ➡️ MATCH (n:`Person`) WHERE n.name = 'arletha.dietric' RETURN n

all persons ❌: [Person(name=arletha.dietric, age=67)]

Comment: This may not have anything to do with your main issue, but `RETURN n, collect(n)` is probably not what you want generated. This is because the `collect` aggregation is using `n` as the [grouping key](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/#grouping-keys), so the value of `collect(n)` will always just be the single-element list `[n]`.

Comment: Do you mean to remove de collect function from my parser class?

```kotlin
    override fun parse(criteria: Criteria): Statement {
        val condition = parseCriteriaToCondition(criteria)
        return Cypher.match(node).where(condition).returning(
            node.requiredSymbolicName, Functions.collect(node)
        ).build()
    }

```

Comment: Try that. It is wasteful to return a node and also a list containing just that node.